# Alternatives to Box-Tidwell transformation for ridge regression?

Tags: r, data-transformation, multicollinearity, ridge-regression, nonlinear

I would like to fit the following model by ridge regression (the xs correlate strongly with one another)

$y = \beta_1 {x_1}^{\lambda_1} + \beta_2 {x_2}^{\lambda_2} + \beta_3 {x_3}^{\lambda_3} + \cdots$

My current approach is to try Box-Tidwell transformation on the $x$s followed by linear ridge regression, but `cv.glmnet` in R throws an error (`lm.fit: NA/NaN/Inf in x`.  There are definitely none of these in my data, nor any zeros; all $x\gt0$ and $y\gt0$).  If you think these errors can be solved both for my current and future data then perhaps the real question is how to do that; example data pasted below if needed.

Assuming Box-Tidwell isn't robust enough for the job (in the everyday sense of the word, not statistical) then what are my alternatives?  Preferably with `R` libraries?

*Data that causes the error, if relevant*

Y

```
2.121973109561620 
1.356081828171345 
3.386240338106292 
4.191699045929254 
3.335211073713898 
3.361101880939723 
1.356081828171345 
4.861907349730742 
3.894757399692251 
1.886732223373362 
1.079580255790821 
1.079580255790821 
2.653488025839402 
2.011958073636261 
3.677721001141955 
0.685538468679168 
3.361101880939723 
2.901321785495637 
0.685538468679168 
3.894757399692251 
2.011958073636261 
0.685538468679168 
4.410650146393066 
1.079580255790821 
2.761096650525593 
0.685538468679168 
0.685538468679168 
3.997709960290063 
0.685538468679168 
1.079580255790821 
1.886732223373362 
3.361101880939723 
3.128459524780916 
1.079580255790821 
3.695194367478646 
4.410650146393066 
4.534314613554609 
2.983752390192320 
1.356081828171345 
1.886732223373362 
3.623052422197949 
4.333074550938076
```

XS (columns are variables)

```
478.666646867709005 3334.999755859999823 8875.997070310000709 18324.000000000000000 73794.968750000000000 84945.000000000000000 86130.000000000000000 97553.000000000000000 95064.997070309997071 216030.000000000000000 259379.000000000000000 
10099.663411979709053 11680.000000000000000 12200.000000000000000 7958.000000000000000 8131.000000000000000 18328.009765599999810 20007.000000000000000 15786.959960899999714 21986.997070310000709 33306.000000000000000 33565.000000000000000 
33075.661458879709244 85765.968750000000000 164516.000000000000000 236134.000000000000000 257607.000000000000000 251330.703125000000000 253966.000000000000000 267988.000000000000000 313167.997070309997071 674297.000000000000000 386713.000000000000000 
18147.663411979709053 43723.000000000000000 112686.968750000000000 232787.000000000000000 359299.000000000000000 416794.687500000000000 448409.000000000000000 456474.000000000000000 580426.997070310055278 1177783.000000000000000 806379.000000000000000 
1751.666341689709043 742.000000000000000 1373.000000000000000 3774.000000000000000 3417.997070309999799 7048.000000000000000 8601.000000000000000 12807.000000000000000 12036.997070310000709 58174.968750000000000 88478.000000000000000 
8614.666341689709952 15974.997070299999905 35111.000000000000000 31349.009765599999810 45828.960937500000000 60135.000000000000000 94882.000000000000000 126677.000000000000000 162313.997070309997071 536617.687500000000000 588591.000000000000000 
1497.666341689709043 1377.000000000000000 1679.000000000000000 1488.000000000000000 2739.000000000000000 3895.997070309999799 4282.000000000000000 6349.000000000000000 7341.997070309999799 17356.000000000000000 15809.000000000000000 
9709.666341689709952 24608.996093800000381 49844.011718800000381 83619.960937500000000 108208.000000000000000 122971.000000000000000 120834.000000000000000 129527.000000000000000 176157.997070309997071 770005.687500000000000 1558291.000000000000000 
3656.666341689708588 10260.997070299999905 9192.000000000000000 19816.000000000000000 40678.011718800000381 66365.960937500000000 83218.000000000000000 96234.000000000000000 90788.997070309997071 122521.000000000000000 68211.000000000000000 
1435.666341689709043 1039.000000000000000 1120.000000000000000 1548.000000000000000 2795.000000000000000 2819.997070309999799 1381.000000000000000 2814.000000000000000 2597.997070309999799 7300.000000000000000 4795.000000000000000 
326.666646867709005 222.000000000000000 233.000000000000000 590.999694824000017 646.000000000000000 1294.000000000000000 902.000000000000000 1876.000000000000000 1755.997070310000026 4264.000000000000000 2435.000000000000000 
15090.663411979709053 30045.000000000000000 51073.011718800000381 56378.960937500000000 74637.000000000000000 113832.000000000000000 99594.000000000000000 107876.000000000000000 92927.997070309997071 124484.000000000000000 90528.000000000000000 
6778.666341689709043 15995.997070299999905 28689.000000000000000 35889.011718800000381 39506.960937500000000 38009.000000000000000 42170.000000000000000 57875.000000000000000 51799.997070309997071 106503.000000000000000 115013.000000000000000 
728.666646867709005 4308.999511719999646 5236.997070309999799 7361.000000000000000 7402.000000000000000 7643.000000000000000 10397.000000000000000 8805.000000000000000 8702.997070310000709 16156.009765599999810 25867.000000000000000 
11485.663411979709053 29994.000000000000000 55584.011718800000381 110733.960938000003807 196418.000000000000000 224935.000000000000000 301638.000000000000000 415136.687500000000000 486633.997070309997071 1537518.000000000000000 2612288.000000000000000 
14.999997049609000 113.000003814999999 569.999938964999956 2424.999755859999823 1697.999694820000059 4809.000000000000000 4335.000000000000000 3392.996948240000165 2.000000000000000 9806.997070310000709 9400.997070310000709 
12241.996419779708958 16586.000000000000000 43257.997070299999905 51420.968750000000000 64047.000000000000000 46403.000000000000000 45279.000000000000000 56147.000000000000000 44679.006835909996880 149701.960938000003807 272353.000000000000000 
600.999944597709032 5093.999511719999646 25560.996093800000381 73356.007812500000000 132986.958007999986876 184185.000000000000000 253398.000000000000000 249111.000000000000000 259542.700195309997071 468466.000000000000000 598152.000000000000000 
2.000000894069000 2.000000000000000 3.999999046330000 261.999938965000013 664.000000000000000 1598.999389650000012 1488.000000000000000 4466.000000000000000 6187.997070309999799 8815.997070310000709 4447.000000000000000 
27280.663411979709053 60442.011718800000381 154128.953125000000000 303640.000000000000000 601715.687500000000000 953291.000000000000000 1463397.000000000000000 1965766.000000000000000 2591598.997070310171694 6003257.000000000000000 6577179.000000000000000 
12.666664034109001 73.000007629400002 223.999954223999993 757.999694824000017 1546.000000000000000 2144.000000000000000 2766.000000000000000 6687.997070309999799 11251.997070310000709 56485.011718800000381 124376.960938000003807 
24.999994188509000 291.999938965000013 1250.000000000000000 1965.999389650000012 6617.000000000000000 868.000000000000000 4410.000000000000000 132.000000000000000 3736.997070309999799 8040.994140630000402 8349.000000000000000 
18833.996419779708958 50967.997070299999905 85909.968750000000000 101534.000000000000000 93684.009765599999810 98219.960937500000000 105931.000000000000000 143515.000000000000000 144080.997070309997071 231816.000000000000000 253980.703125000000000 
181.000020891708999 698.999938964999956 648.000000000000000 557.999389648000033 803.000000000000000 1047.000000000000000 423.000000000000000 1839.000000000000000 2772.997070309999799 3955.000000000000000 2865.000000000000000 
220.666631608708997 479.000000000000000 999.999694824000017 1255.000000000000000 4805.000000000000000 1357.000000000000000 7213.997070309999799 2235.000000000000000 2047.997070310000026 2.000000000000000 2991.000000000000000 
2.000000000000000 18.999996900599999 218.999977112000010 933.999969481999983 1800.999450680000109 7763.000000000000000 9354.997070310000709 2147.000000000000000 4617.997070309999799 9389.997070310000709 2.000000000000000 
2.000000059604000 4.999999761580000 55.999992370599998 161.999980926999996 431.999954224000021 1728.999694820000059 2003.999694820000059 3507.000000000000000 4759.997070309999799 16910.994140599999810 22492.000000000000000 
475.999944597709032 2699.999450679999882 9437.000000000000000 35624.996093800000381 110005.965819999997620 230986.000000000000000 389725.000000000000000 489768.687500000000000 540855.997070310055278 689805.000000000000000 557554.000000000000000 
208.999975114708974 487.999969481999983 865.000000000000000 1298.999389650000012 1367.000000000000000 2181.000000000000000 2760.000000000000000 4338.000000000000000 4262.997070309999799 7572.994140630000402 5933.000000000000000 
13.999999910609001 258.999938965000013 700.000000000000000 4038.999450679999882 1804.000000000000000 2.000000000000000 3711.000000000000000 2.000000000000000 2893.997070309999799 9079.997070310000709 15039.000000000000000 
145.999961763708995 443.999969481999983 1364.999694820000059 3855.999755859999823 8110.000000000000000 18502.994140599999810 27661.000000000000000 57368.011718800000381 89620.958007809997071 275004.000000000000000 570516.009765999973752 
9875.999349509709646 30551.996093800000381 62530.008789100000286 125178.960938000003807 210236.000000000000000 341185.011719000001904 598850.648438000003807 965927.000000000000000 1534750.997070309938863 4654071.000000000000000 5840271.000000000000000 
7055.666341689709043 16131.997070299999905 15552.000000000000000 21378.000000000000000 51034.968750000000000 85692.000000000000000 134986.000000000000000 233489.000000000000000 280857.997070309997071 517137.687500000000000 554130.000000000000000 
184.000020891708999 1451.999877929999911 12273.999755900000309 28868.993164100000286 1043.000000000000000 10414.000000000000000 10303.000000000000000 3733.000000000000000 18091.997070310000709 30986.009765599999810 59903.011718800000381 
3310.999349509708736 5260.000000000000000 8476.997070310000709 12254.997070299999905 25941.000000000000000 63078.000000000000000 113956.937500000000000 171371.000000000000000 230371.997070309997071 522103.000000000000000 647156.687500000000000 
9667.666341689709952 20902.996093800000381 42888.011718800000381 76499.960937500000000 110618.000000000000000 175940.000000000000000 213728.000000000000000 193852.000000000000000 154408.997070309997071 322866.687500000000000 361995.000000000000000 
3845.999349509708736 22311.996093800000381 60476.008789100000286 114873.960938000003807 231065.000000000000000 433093.009765999973752 637188.687500000000000 736014.959961000015028 754746.997070310055278 1528714.000000000000000 1540701.000000000000000 
4525.999349509709646 16227.997070299999905 43726.997070299999905 75031.968750000000000 105352.000000000000000 129998.000000000000000 166115.000000000000000 219251.009766000002855 267542.997070309997071 643765.648438000003807 947828.000000000000000 
3696.999654679708783 10310.996826200000214 17780.000000000000000 20852.000000000000000 28198.009765599999810 50840.958007799999905 50278.000000000000000 87680.000000000000000 129214.997070309997071 398212.000000000000000 670668.687500000000000 
54.999992281209003 259.999938965000013 808.000000000000000 2680.999450679999882 8467.000000000000000 21471.997070299999905 32668.997070299999905 59477.968750000000000 90554.997070309997071 267148.000000000000000 571955.009765999973752 
1435.999959859708952 5265.999206540000159 15566.997070299999905 26677.000000000000000 38977.008789100000286 45958.960937500000000 53466.000000000000000 61751.000000000000000 40377.997070309997071 52698.000000000000000 63474.000000000000000 
1067.666341689709043 6814.000000000000000 30005.996093800000381 52336.011718800000381 113843.960938000003807 168087.000000000000000 227640.000000000000000 306229.000000000000000 340356.684570309997071 650659.000000000000000 878088.000000000000000
```

Comment: I count 42 observations, 11 predictors and an inclination to fit a model with 22 parameters. In addition to high correlations, I see everywhere skewness and long tails in the $X$. One might guess that $\lambda_j <1$ would help, but the aim seems over-optimistic. Why do you think the model is even plausible? Is there some physics (or whatever the field is) here that motivates the model?  Would you trust the model fit if you could get one? The individual terms are power functions, but the distribution of your response is about uniform and doesn't seem obviously compatible with that idea.

Comment: All that said, nonlinear least squares seems an obvious alternative, but I remain queasy at the prospect.

Comment: Some puzzling granularity in $Y$. A frequency table starts  6 values at  .6855385, 5 at 1.07958, 3 at 1.356082,  3 at 1.886732,  2 at  2.011958.

Comment: All good points.  The response variable was also a power function but has been Box Cox transformed already.  I hadn't looked at the degrees of freedom in this model: it's test data, I'm trying to develop a generic procedure to use for other problems of the same type.  The problem is transport modelling where I literally do expect all variables to have an influence, albeit some not measurably from the collected data.  Hence using ridge/lasso regression, and generalized cross validation r2 for the fit, to get predictions I can trust.

Comment: At least this is what I did before introducing these power terms (previously I just Box-Coxed each predictor variable but now I gather Box-Tidwell is supposed to be the thing for predictors).

Comment: re NLLS: Is it possible to do regularlized nonlinear least squares (ridge or lasso)?  Is there an R package for it?

Comment: As often, it is much easier to spot problems than to suggest solutions.   If you transform the $X$, there would seem to be merit in transforming them in the same way.  I don't know whether there is work on combining nonlinear LS and ridge/lasso: sounds unlikely to me, but that is just visceral. Even if this is test data, models as complicated as yours require much bigger datasets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33917/discussion-between-sideshow-bob-and-nick-cox).

Comment: I can't really add much, except to say that if your functional form has physical motivation, the same won't carry over to transformed response.

Comment: I do agree, though that's another problem for another day!

Comment: I don't see that you can postpone the question. The functional form has no rationale otherwise. What is additive on one scale won't be additive on any nonlinearly transformed scale. Otherwise put, you seem to be saying that (a) there are grounds for treating the response as measured as a sum of power functions (b) you've decided to transform the response for other reasons. The two aren't independent. It's like starting with an additive model, and then deciding that you want to log transform the response but keep an additive form. That may be a better model, but it's not the same model.

Comment: Add a fitting overtone of "it's your problem, naturally, and you'll know of subtleties and constraints that bite in practice".

Comment: On physical grounds I would ideally like a model that's an untransformed linear sum of power transformed predictors which are multicollinear.  However the variance in the response is expected to be larger for larger $Y$, i.e. $Y = \Sigma \beta X^\lambda + \epsilon Y$.  Hence the transform of $Y$.  It is acceptable to handle the heteroscedasticity instead by weighting each point by (say) $1/Y$?

Comment: Am I right in thinking the following R packages might perform regularized NLLS? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/minpack.lm/minpack.lm.pdf https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gnm/vignettes/gnmOverview.pdf

Comment: Sorry, but I can't advise on R.